# "DISK NOT EJECTED PROPERLY" every 60 seconds or so

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb

I attached a 2T magnetic, spinning USB disk to my Mac mini today, and started getting:

```
DISK NOT EJECTED PROPERLY
Eject "Untitled" before disconnecting or turning it off.
```

But I'm not ejecting it or removing it, and I'm not futzing with the cabling.

It happens pretty precisely every 60 seconds.  It's a pain to keep dismissing all the popups.

I do not have Energy Saver set up on the drive in macOS.  And I am currently running a backup to it, so it's probably not idle.

This hardware worked fine on a Linux system.

I'm using macOS 11.5.2.

Any suggestions?

Here's a 10 second log:

```
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL
2021-09-05 07:55:29.089598-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:default] Rescoring all 201 activities [<private>]
2021-09-05 07:55:29.089617-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd69             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.089857-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6a             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.090401-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6b             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.090566-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 502:com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent.persistent-history-cleanup:6EBB39:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
    {name: RestartRequiredActivitiesPolicy, policyWeight: 1.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{DeviceRestartPeriodNotInRange == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.090887-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6c             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091047-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.fullanalysis:B0253C:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091165-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6d             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091484-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photos.face:F825BE:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091609-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6e             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091756-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photosanalysis:BAF4FC:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091890-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6f             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092066-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 0:com.apple.apsd.apprefresh:3E26F1:[
    {name: PowerNapPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{inADarkWake == 0 AND appRefresh == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092211-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd70             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092361-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 0:com.apple.rtcreportingd:NRM:01490D:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092489-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd71             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092817-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 0:com.apple.aned.temporaryFilesMaintenance:388C82:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.093226-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:default] Setting timer (isWaking=1, activityRequiresWaking=0) between <private> and <private> for <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:29.938380-0700 0x87cc3    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:30.177521-0700 0x8892a    Info        0x0                  211    0    symptomsd: (SymptomEvaluator) [com.apple.symptomsd:analytics] Data Usage for com.google.Chrome - WiFi in/out: 889092/114532, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:31.179307-0700 0x87cc3    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:32.396379-0700 0x87a2d    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:32.830417-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (EndpointSecurity) Task has not been granted user permission to connect
2021-09-05 07:55:32.830425-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  386    0    com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent: (libEndpointSecurity.dylib) Failed to open service: -536870174
2021-09-05 07:55:32.831952-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (EndpointSecurity) Task has not been granted user permission to connect
2021-09-05 07:55:32.831958-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  386    0    com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent: (libEndpointSecurity.dylib) Failed to open service: -536870174
2021-09-05 07:55:32.925625-0700 0xcc4      Info        0x0                  446    0    thermald: [thermald:log] 50/0/0 SFI:25/25/19/0/0/0 GPU:0/0/0/0 IO:0/0/0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:33.591622-0700 0x87aa8    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097590-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166329443: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097595-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166414807: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097598-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166419342: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097600-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166419868: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097601-0700 0x88927    Default     0x0                  94     0    remoted: [com.apple.xpc.remote:remoted] localbridge> Sending heartbeat request 8079
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097602-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166420283: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097617-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:connection] [0x7fbba2906010] Enqueueing send of 3f1b
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097619-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:connection] [0x7fbba2906010] Send initiated
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097620-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:channel] [0x7fbba290b490] Starting write of msg_id 16155 (80 bytes).
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097720-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:channel] [0x7fbba290b490] Send of msg_id 16155 completed successfully
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097721-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:connection] [0x7fbba2906010] Send completed
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097725-0700 0x88925    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:connection] nw_flow_service_writes [C5 IPv6#4a16cc3f%en6.59602 ready socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en6, scoped)] No unblocked write requests, stopping servicing writes
2021-09-05 07:55:34.100338-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:channel] Delivering 16155
2021-09-05 07:55:34.100343-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:connection] [0x7fbba2906010] Message 3f1b received , dispatching handler block
2021-09-05 07:55:34.100363-0700 0x88925    Default     0x0                  94     0    remoted: [com.apple.xpc.remote:remoted] localbridge> Heartbeat 8079 succeeded
2021-09-05 07:55:34.100401-0700 0x88925    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: [com.apple.xpc.remote:watchdog] remote_device_heartbeat() on bridge result: yes
2021-09-05 07:55:34.145414-0700 0x27a      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) tx_flush:1182: disk1 xid 755862 tx stats: # 11200 finish 8234 enter 1939 wait 1479 36895us close 129us flush 38223us
2021-09-05 07:55:34.803858-0700 0x87cc3    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:35.005931-0700 0x888fb    Info        0x0                  211    0    symptomsd: (SymptomEvaluator) [com.apple.symptomsd:analytics] Data Usage for com.google.Chrome - WiFi in/out: 889092/114532, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:35.640829-0700 0x8892a    Info        0x0                  211    0    symptomsd: (SymptomEvaluator) [com.apple.symptomsd:analytics] Data Usage for com.google.Chrome - WiFi in/out: 889092/114532, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:36.030308-0700 0x87cc3    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:37.164876-0700 0x888fb    Info        0x0                  211    0    symptomsd: (SymptomEvaluator) [com.apple.symptomsd:analytics] Data Usage for com.google.Chrome - WiFi in/out: 889092/114532, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:37.249448-0700 0x87a2d    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:38.331977-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (EndpointSecurity) Task has not been granted user permission to connect
2021-09-05 07:55:38.331985-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  386    0    com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent: (libEndpointSecurity.dylib) Failed to open service: -536870174
2021-09-05 07:55:38.334451-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (EndpointSecurity) Task has not been granted user permission to connect
2021-09-05 07:55:38.334457-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  386    0    com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent: (libEndpointSecurity.dylib) Failed to open service: -536870174
2021-09-05 07:55:38.453485-0700 0x87aa8    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:38.588204-0700 0x87a2d    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=73484 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:39.011005-0700 0x358      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (Sandbox) Sandbox: 31 duplicate reports for com.crowdstrike. deny(1) system-privilege 1016
2021-09-05 07:55:39.011008-0700 0x358      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (Sandbox) Sandbox: logd_helper(149) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/FortiClient.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/assets/js/guimessenger_jyp.node
above cmd output done    2021 Sun Sep 05 07:58:05 AM PDT
root@Mac-mini:/var/log x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0 73513

$ 2021-09-05 07:53:43.644789-0700 0x88588    Default     0x15a92c             614    3    sharingd: (CoreUtils) [com.apple.sharing:TetheringAgent] Adding client proxy (ClientID e2de4646-c6e0-45c6-bc6b-53840$ cat /tmp/log.txt
$ cat /tmp/log.txt
cmd output started 2021 Sun Sep 05 07:58:22 AM PDT
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL
2021-09-05 07:55:29.089598-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:default] Rescoring all 201 activities [<private>]
2021-09-05 07:55:29.089617-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd69             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.089857-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6a             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.090401-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6b             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.090566-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 502:com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent.persistent-history-cleanup:6EBB39:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
    {name: RestartRequiredActivitiesPolicy, policyWeight: 1.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{DeviceRestartPeriodNotInRange == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.090887-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6c             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091047-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.fullanalysis:B0253C:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091165-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6d             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091484-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photos.face:F825BE:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091609-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6e             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091756-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photosanalysis:BAF4FC:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.091890-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd6f             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092066-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 0:com.apple.apsd.apprefresh:3E26F1:[
    {name: PowerNapPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{inADarkWake == 0 AND appRefresh == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092211-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd70             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092361-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 0:com.apple.rtcreportingd:NRM:01490D:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092489-0700 0x88914    Activity    0x15bd71             131    0    dasd: (CoreDuetContext) Duet: ClientContext objectForContextualKeyPath:
2021-09-05 07:55:29.092817-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:scoring] 0:com.apple.aned.temporaryFilesMaintenance:388C82:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
2021-09-05 07:55:29.093226-0700 0x88914    Default     0x0                  131    8    dasd: [com.apple.duetactivityscheduler:default] Setting timer (isWaking=1, activityRequiresWaking=0) between <private> and <private> for <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:29.938380-0700 0x87cc3    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:30.177521-0700 0x8892a    Info        0x0                  211    0    symptomsd: (SymptomEvaluator) [com.apple.symptomsd:analytics] Data Usage for com.google.Chrome - WiFi in/out: 889092/114532, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:31.179307-0700 0x87cc3    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:32.396379-0700 0x87a2d    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:32.830417-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (EndpointSecurity) Task has not been granted user permission to connect
2021-09-05 07:55:32.830425-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  386    0    com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent: (libEndpointSecurity.dylib) Failed to open service: -536870174
2021-09-05 07:55:32.831952-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (EndpointSecurity) Task has not been granted user permission to connect
2021-09-05 07:55:32.831958-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  386    0    com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent: (libEndpointSecurity.dylib) Failed to open service: -536870174
2021-09-05 07:55:32.925625-0700 0xcc4      Info        0x0                  446    0    thermald: [thermald:log] 50/0/0 SFI:25/25/19/0/0/0 GPU:0/0/0/0 IO:0/0/0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:33.591622-0700 0x87aa8    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097590-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166329443: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097595-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166414807: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097598-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166419342: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097600-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166419868: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097601-0700 0x88927    Default     0x0                  94     0    remoted: [com.apple.xpc.remote:remoted] localbridge> Sending heartbeat request 8079
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097602-0700 0x864c9    Info        0x0                  102    0    watchdogd: [com.apple.watchdogd:service-monitoring-thread] 80799166420283: <private>
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097617-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:connection] [0x7fbba2906010] Enqueueing send of 3f1b
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097619-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:connection] [0x7fbba2906010] Send initiated
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097620-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:channel] [0x7fbba290b490] Starting write of msg_id 16155 (80 bytes).
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097720-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:channel] [0x7fbba290b490] Send of msg_id 16155 completed successfully
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097721-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:connection] [0x7fbba2906010] Send completed
2021-09-05 07:55:34.097725-0700 0x88925    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (libnetwork.dylib) [com.apple.network:connection] nw_flow_service_writes [C5 IPv6#4a16cc3f%en6.59602 ready socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en6, scoped)] No unblocked write requests, stopping servicing writes
2021-09-05 07:55:34.100338-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:channel] Delivering 16155
2021-09-05 07:55:34.100343-0700 0x88927    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: (RemoteXPC) [com.apple.xpc.remote:connection] [0x7fbba2906010] Message 3f1b received , dispatching handler block
2021-09-05 07:55:34.100363-0700 0x88925    Default     0x0                  94     0    remoted: [com.apple.xpc.remote:remoted] localbridge> Heartbeat 8079 succeeded
2021-09-05 07:55:34.100401-0700 0x88925    Info        0x0                  94     0    remoted: [com.apple.xpc.remote:watchdog] remote_device_heartbeat() on bridge result: yes
2021-09-05 07:55:34.145414-0700 0x27a      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) tx_flush:1182: disk1 xid 755862 tx stats: # 11200 finish 8234 enter 1939 wait 1479 36895us close 129us flush 38223us
2021-09-05 07:55:34.803858-0700 0x87cc3    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:35.005931-0700 0x888fb    Info        0x0                  211    0    symptomsd: (SymptomEvaluator) [com.apple.symptomsd:analytics] Data Usage for com.google.Chrome - WiFi in/out: 889092/114532, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:35.640829-0700 0x8892a    Info        0x0                  211    0    symptomsd: (SymptomEvaluator) [com.apple.symptomsd:analytics] Data Usage for com.google.Chrome - WiFi in/out: 889092/114532, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:36.030308-0700 0x87cc3    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:37.164876-0700 0x888fb    Info        0x0                  211    0    symptomsd: (SymptomEvaluator) [com.apple.symptomsd:analytics] Data Usage for com.google.Chrome - WiFi in/out: 889092/114532, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 0/0
2021-09-05 07:55:37.249448-0700 0x87a2d    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:38.331977-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (EndpointSecurity) Task has not been granted user permission to connect
2021-09-05 07:55:38.331985-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  386    0    com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent: (libEndpointSecurity.dylib) Failed to open service: -536870174
2021-09-05 07:55:38.334451-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (EndpointSecurity) Task has not been granted user permission to connect
2021-09-05 07:55:38.334457-0700 0x8859c    Error       0x0                  386    0    com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent: (libEndpointSecurity.dylib) Failed to open service: -536870174
2021-09-05 07:55:38.453485-0700 0x87aa8    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=2210 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:38.588204-0700 0x87a2d    Default     0x0                  2111   0    pidinfo: proc_pidinfo flavor=9 pid=73484 arg=0 size=2352 returned 0 with errno 1
2021-09-05 07:55:39.011005-0700 0x358      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (Sandbox) Sandbox: 31 duplicate reports for com.crowdstrike. deny(1) system-privilege 1016
2021-09-05 07:55:39.011008-0700 0x358      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (Sandbox) Sandbox: logd_helper(149) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/FortiClient.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/assets/js/guimessenger_jyp.node
```

Comment: First guess is a periodic USB device controller reset on the device side. May be an issue specific to the interaction of 11.5.2's driver stack with the device firmware/hardware. **(1)** Who is the HDD vendor? **(2)** I'm assuming that you did *not* install any special drivers, correct? **(3)** Can you share log output around the time of failure? Enter this command into a Terminal window but don't press Return yet. As soon as you see the failure message, hit Return, then copy the output and add it to your question `log show --info --debug --last 10s` Make sure to scrub output for personal data!

Comment: A brand new drive? What if you format it? Does it still happen? @pion has some good suggestions but I would bet that the USB interface or drive controller is bad and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Yes I'm suspecting a flaky controller. Wanting to see log output for hints that would corroborate this.

Comment: Also are you connecting this directly to your Mac or through a USB hub? Have you tried swapping cables? Switching to all available USB ports on your Mac? (These symptoms could be the result of a topology brownout cascade.)

Comment: How is the drive powered? If it's getting inadequate or inconsistent power, that might cause the controller to flake out.

Comment: It's not happening 100% consistently.  In fact, for a while I thought the problem went away.  But overnight, there was another cascade of the popup previously mentioned.

Comment: It's not a new drive.  In fact, it's been a while since I used it for anything.  I did just lay down a new APFS on it though - it was an XFS previously, when I had it on a Linux system.

Comment: @pion The disk is directly connected to my mac mini. I have a USB hub on the system, but this is a direct connect.

Comment: @pion I have not tried a different cable yet. I do have another. I'll try it RSN :)

Comment: The drive is powered by a powerstrip that's plugged into a second powerstrip, that's plugged into my wall.

Comment: @dstromberg Try switching to every available port on the Mac and living on that port for a while to see if it makes a difference (the signal routing does change with each unique port and I've seen this make a difference on several occasions).

Comment: @dstromberg Also I would try disconnecting your USB hub (and any other devices) from your Mac for as long as possible. There can also be funny interactions in the driver stack between seemingly unrelated/unconnected devices.

Comment: @dstromberg I'm perplexed by how sparse your log output is. Are you by chance omitting a bunch of lines? Can you try running the following command in the background and then when you see the failure occur, quickly Ctrl-C it to stop output and then copy-paste the last ~10 seconds worth of data? (It should be theoretically the same as if you ran `log show`, though...) `log stream --info --debug`

Comment: I'm suspecting this was a heat problem.  The disk didn't show the problem for quite a while, but then it started again, a little less frequently.  I opened the external USB enclosure and touched the disk.  The top of the enclosure was cool, but the disk was uncomfortably hot to the touch.  I've moved the disk off my mac mini (the disk had been physically on top of the mini) and to somewhere it can cool better.  Jury's still out though.